# Unterschied zwischen „du hättest (…) sollen“ und „du solltest (…) haben“

Tags: subjunctive, perfect-tense, tense

Gesetzt den Fall, dass die folgenden Sätze richtig sind, könnte jemand den Unterschied erklären?

> *Du hättest das früher erledigen sollen.* (Konjunktiv Perfekt)

und

> *Du solltest das früher erledigt haben.* (*für mich unbekannte Zeit*)

Ein Beispiel wäre mir sehr hilfreich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich stimme nicht ganz der anderen Antwort zu.

> Du solltest das früher erledigt haben

Ich sehe das nicht zwingend in der Zukunft. Vor allen Dingen nicht in ferner Zukunft. Das im Kommentar angesprochene "in Richtung Futur II" wäre ja irgendwas mit *werden*. Also beispielsweise:

> Du wirst das früher erledigt haben

*Solltest* ist aber erstmal Präteritum, sowohl Indikativ als auch Konjunktiv. Ein typisches Beispiel für den Konjunktiv ist:

> Solltest du früher fertig werden, kannst du mir dann noch helfen?

Das heißt soviel wie: "Falls du früher fertig wirst, dann hilfst du mir doch bitte."

In OPs Beispiel ist das Verb aber wahrscheinlich im Indikativ und die Handlung, auf die Bezug genommen wird, liegt in der Vergangenheit

> Du solltest das (doch) früher erledigt haben. Wo sind die Ergebnisse?

Ein anderes, ähnliches Beispiel zeigt, dass der Satz aber sowohl Indikativ (und somit Vergangenheit) als auch Konjunktiv (und somit nahe Zukunft) sein kann:

> Du solltest das doch noch vor dem Mittagessen erledigt haben. Warum hast du es nicht gemacht?
>   Du solltest das doch noch vor dem Mittagessen erledigt haben. Jetzt aber schnell.

Zugegeben, ohne eine Partikel – wie in OPs Beispiel – klingt der Satz etwas merkwürdig. Ist aber durchaus möglich.

---

Bzgl. "hättest erledigt haben sollen" stimme ich der anderen Antwort zu.

Answer (score 2):

„Du hättest das früher erledigen sollen“

Hier liegt alles in der Vergangenheit, du hättest die Steuererklärung schon viel früher erledigen sollen, dann wäre es gegen Ende des Jahres nämlich nicht so knapp gewesen (Rückblick).

„Du solltest das früher erledigt haben“

Das, was du erledigen sollst, liegt in der Zukunft. 
Die Steuererklärung ist noch nicht gemacht, du solltest aber rechtzeitig damit anfangen (vorausschauend). 
Nächstes Jahr um diese Zeit, solltest du es also erledigt haben.

Comment: hättest du vielleicht auch das Tempus für den zweiten satz?

Comment: Steuern! Schönes Thema! ...ne, danke! :)

Comment: Tempus für Satz 2? Gute Frage.
Ist ein bisschen in Richtung Futur II, also eine abgeschlossene Handlung in der Zukunft. Ich weiß es aber nicht^^